# Problemas no carrinho PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Segue o código do meu carrinho. Eu queria que ele não repetisse os produtos e sim soma-se a quantidade deles no carrinho. Estou com dificuldade nessa parte.

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
session_start();
$_SESSION['carrinho'][] = $_GET['produtoid'];
?>
```

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    table, tr, td{
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

</style>
```

```
<table>

    <tr>

        <td>Nome</td>

        <td>Quantidade</td>

        <td>Subtotal</td>

    </tr>


    <?php

         for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['carrinho']); $i++){

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM produto where id =".$_SESSION['carrinho'][$i]." ";

         $resultado = $PDO->query($consulta); 

         $vetorResultado = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

         foreach ($vetorResultado as $valor) {

            echo "<tr><td>".$valor['nome']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' size='3' name='vetorResultado['id']' value='1'></td>";
            echo "<td>".$valor['preco']."</td></tr>";
      }







    }


    ?>

</table>
```

Finalizar compra
Continuar comprando

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Leonardo, como você está guardando esses dados no banco de dados você pode alterar um pouco sua query e retornar a quantidade de produtos agrupando os registros.

```
$consulta = "SELECT nome,preco,count(nome) as qtd FROM produto where id =".$_SESSION['carrinho'][$i]." group by nome,preco";
```

Essa query vai te retornar `nome`, `preco` e `qtd` (quantidade de linhas agrupadas). Ai então é só alterar seu loop.

```
foreach ($vetorResultado as $valor) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$valor['nome']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' size='3' name='vetorResultado['id']' value='".$valor['qtd']."'></td>";
    echo "<td>".$valor['preco']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Tenta isso.